# Change app name and bundle id to upload it in another app on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have **2 apps on iTunes connect**. One for dev and one for production (2 different app names).

I have made a lot of changes on the dev project and I would like to **make the dev app available in the production app on iTunes connect** to then deploy it to the App Store.

The first idea that came to my mind was to **rename the dev project** (and bundle id) to match the one from the production app. And then I would just have to archive the dev app and upload it, in hope that it will be shown in the production app on iTunes connect.

**My questions are** :

1. Is it the way to go ? If so, I am using Firebase and a lot of pods; Do I have to make changes in the .xcodeproj or the .xcworkspace file ? Then do I have something to do with the pods, certificates, app files, … ?
2. Is there another (and better) way to do that ?
3. Can you please provide me a link explaining this process ? I did not find anything…

**One another thing**
 
I know that working with 2 different apps is not the best way for dev and production environments. What solution would you recommend ? Knowing that I have 2 firebase projects (one for dev and one for production)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Of course having two different apps just to work with development and production environment is not a good choice. You can either do **conditional coding** or you can make **multiple targets** in your app to support different configurations or environments.

For conditional coding, You can make a global variable which you can use throughout the project to identify the environment and use that variable to differentiate between what code to be used or applied in that particular environment.

For more info on how to use multiple targets in app refer below blog posts:
https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/

https://medium.com/@jigarm/how-to-create-multiple-targets-ios-app-480d52a762d2

https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/xcode-targets-with-multiples-build-configuration-90a575ddc687

For more info on **supporting multiple firebase app in single app** refer this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this ! It will definitely help me :) But right now I really need to rename my Xcode project, can you also help me sort this out ?

Comment: You can change name and bundleID for project. It should match the bundle id of app created on appstore. You can change project name(display name) and bundle ID at any point of time. You will need to create two different apps on appstore and make sure to match the profile and bundle id of the app with xcode project while uploading.

Comment: Ok so I change the name and bundle id in my .xcodeproj or my .xcworspace file ?

Comment: If you have a .xcworspace, open it. Go to target and change the bundle id and name there.

Comment: Ok and nothing more to do ? No other file to edit or anything ? A ‘pod install’ I suppose but nothing more ?